# Ajaxifying php page result data

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

I want to send mail by user to domain@host.com after filling contact us form.
On successful sending or fail sending in both situation Message is shown in new page, I want to show these messages on my contact us page after submitting.

**html**

```
    <form  id="form"class="form" action="sendEmail.php" method="POST">

    <p class="name">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe" />
        <label for="name">Name</label>
    </p>

    <p class="email">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    </p>

    <p class="subject">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="www.example.com" />
        <label for="subject">subject</label>
    </p>        

    <p class="text">
        <textarea name="message" id="comment" placeholder="Write something to us" /></textarea>
    </p>
              <div id="complete" class="complete hide">
        <h3>Thank you</h3>
        <p>We will be in contact with you soon!</p>
      </div>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>




</form>
```

### Here is my sendEmail.php code

```
        <?php
    $toAddress = 'domain@host.com'; //eamil will be sent to this account...
    $EmailSentBy= $_POST['email'];
    $userEmail = $_POST['name'];
    $title = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    //****************************************************************


    require 'PHPMailer-5.2.23/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail -> isSMTP();

    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail -> SMTPDebug = 0;

    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail -> Debugoutput = 'html';

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail -> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';///
    // use
    // $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail -> Port = 587;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail -> Username = "domain@host.com";//email address from which it is send to other // 

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail -> Password = "ooovxxazwdbxmcgn";//password of website email account

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail -> setFrom($toAddress, "Contact Us Page");

    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail -> addReplyTo($userEmail, "UserName here");

    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail -> addAddress($toAddress, "Mr/Mrs.");//receiver

    //Set the subject line
    $mail -> Subject = $title;


    $msg = 'Message';

    //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
    $mail -> msgHTML($msg);

    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail -> AltBody = 'This is an auto generated email from oric.uob.edu.pk';

    //Attach an image file
    //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');


    //************************************************************************
    if (!$mail -> send()) {

   echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'There was a problem while sending Email' . $mailer -> ErrorInfo));

die();

}else{

echo json_encode(array('status' => TRUE, 'msg' => 'Successfully Approved'));
die();
    }
    ?>
```

**Jscript**

```
    $(function() {
  var form = $('#form');


  $(form).submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      response=$("#msg").html("<i>Thank you </i>")

    })
    .fail(function(data) {

    });
  })
});
```

I am unable to find out whats going wrong, any kind of help would be very appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you kidding me? how  you are supposed to achieve what you want to if you dont even call them in Jscript.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. The HTML for the page containing your form is missing from your question. The PHP is largely irrelevant (at least unless you've debugged things sufficiently to determine that you are getting the wrong response back from the PHP).

Comment: I am getting the response But it redirects to other page and show response data there

Comment: Are any errors reported in the Console of the Developer Tools? (Ensure you have it configured to preserve logs between page loads).

Comment: No there are no such errors.

Comment: @khan what do you mean I am calling them in response check my code.

Comment: @naizoric — When that comment was made, there was no `<form>` for the event to attach to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the result data from sendEmail.php in Jscript properly because you are using Status and msg in your `echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'There was a problem while sending Email' . $mailer -> ErrorInfo));`
You should remove method=post in your form tag using both might get you in trouble
create Jscript function and using onClick attribute in your submint button.

```
<input type="submit" onClick="myfun()"/>
```

**Jscript**

```
function myfun()
{
        var data = $("#loginForm").serialize();// form ki id 

    $.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    url : "process/login.php",  //process file
    dataType : "json",
    //data : data,
    }).done(function(data) {
    status = data["status"];


    if (status == true | status=="true") {
    msg1 = data["msg"];
    msg = msg1;
    alert(msg);

    } else {

    msg1 = data["msg"];
    // alert(msg);
    msg = msg1;
    var Error_message = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>  <strong> <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i></strong>  ' + msg + '</div>';
    response.html(Error_message);

    }

    }).fail(function(x, y, z) {
    var msg = x.responseText;
    alert(msg);

    response.html(x + y + z);
    });
}
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: "You are not getting the result data from sendEmail.php in Jscript because you are using Status and msg in your" — How does using those particular key names prevent the data being received by JavaScript?

Comment: "using onClick attribute in your submint button" — Don't do that! (a) This isn't 1997 now. We have the ability to bind event handlers from JavaScript (which the existing code is already doing). (b) Now you are no longer preventing the default action of the form submission, which will create the problem the question is describing.

Comment: @Quentin havnt you noticed  status = data["status"] in my code ? and My suggested approach solved his problem. There are more then one way to perform the task I came up this.

Comment: @Quentin using particular key names does not prevent data being received by javascript but does not perform as you would want them to like if status =true do this else do that..

Answer (score 2):

I think you should chose between submitting your form data by POST (using `<form method="POST">` or by ajax using `$.ajax()`) but you should not use both.

Currently, your Javascript is bypassed : when you click on the submit button, the browser is requesting `sendEmail.php` and waits for a response without calling your JavaScript.

If you want the rendered `sendEmail.php` displayed on the same page, you should change

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

to

```
<button id="sendmail">Send</button>
```

and then select it with Jquery with something like

```
$('#sendmail').on('click', function(e) { /* your AJAX goes here */ });
```

Moreover, you should be aware that everyone who is able to generate a POST request will be able to abuse your PHP script and send arbitrary emails using your mail account

Comment: "but you should not use both" — This is bad advice. Unobtrusive JavaScript / Progressive Enhancement is a good design philosophy.

Comment: "when you click on the submit button, the browser is requesting sendEmail.php and waits for a response without calling your JavaScript" — It shouldn't be. The JavaScript is binding a submit event handler that prevents the default action of the form.

Comment: `<button id="sendmail">Send</button>` — The default button type is `submit` so that makes no difference at all.